# VSCode auto suggest latest versions pip requirements.txt

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, autosuggest

**Identify an unkown feature**

On a previous VSCode installation (OSX Vscode 1.7.x), a feature was enabled that auto suggested the 3rd party dependencies in the pip `requirements.txt` file.

I am on a fresh install of VSCode(1.71.2 linux) and have both

- Microsoft Python(v2022.16.1)
- Pylance(v2022.10.20)

extensions installed, but the feature of "auto suggest latest versions" is not showing/working.

My google-foo is failing to locate either what "extension" provided that feature, or if already installed, how to install it. I don't know what it is called.

It "behaves" like an auto suggest above the `3rdparty==1.2.3` library entry.
and also marks ones with CVE's in red.

It always auto-detected `requirements.txt` and `requirements-*.txt` files.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was called PyPi Assistant.
I found that by searching in VSCode with

```
@popular pip
```